# Let $K\leq G$ be a closed subgroup of a compact lie group G. I would like to see examples with $H^{1}(K,\mathbb{R})=0$.

Tags: lie-groups, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $K\leq G$ be a closed subgroup of  a compact lie group G, where do I find examples with $H^{1}(K,\mathbb{R})=0$?

Comment: For example, $G\times \{e\}$ is a subgroup of $G\times G$ wherever $H^1(G)=0$; or $Spin(n)$ is a subgroup of $Spin(n+1)$, or even $SO(n)$ is a subgroup of $SO(n+1)$ and $H^1=0$ if you use De Rham.. why, do you want a "full classification"?

Comment: I want to construct examples for a global version of Reeb-Thurston Stability Theorem: Let $M$ a compact smooth manifold and $\mathcal{F}$ a Hausdorff regular foliation  in $M$. If there exist a generic leaf $L$ with $H^{1}(L)=0$, then $\mathcal{F}$ is $C^{\infty}$ stable. 
In the case of Lie groups is more easier, because $G/K$ is Hausdorff and the orbits of left action $K$ in $G$ is a foliation.